# Variables from a table that not exist in another one

Tags: mysql

Hello everybody i am currently trying to get the variables from one table that not exist in a second in mysql , for example i have this code

```
SELECT students.`StudentID`
From students
JOIN studentsdays ON studentsdays.`StudentID`=students.`StudentID`
JOIN studentshours ON studentshours.`StudentID`=students.`StudentID`
JOIN studentclassroom ON studentclassroom.`StudentID`=students.`StudentID`
JOIN attendance ON attendance.`StudentID` = students.`StudentID`
WHERE dayID='14mon' and hoursid='ora2' and ClassRoomID=101 and CourseID =1111
```

Which displays the following table

```
StudentID
----------
 11111
----------
 22222
----------
 33333
```

The second code

```
SELECT user_id FROM demo_log
```

Displays the following table

```
user_id
----------
 11111
----------
 22222
```

How can i put this codes together to get a table that will have the values that are only on the first table , give a table like this one

```
StudentID
----------
 33333
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select a.*
from (
    -- Your first (big) query
    select ...
    ) as a 
    left join demo_log as b on a.user_id = b.student_id
where b.user_id is null
-- add any other where conditions you need
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will match all rows from the first query with the rows of the `demo_log` table; for each non matching row there will be a `NULL` value corresponding to the `demo_log` column(s). If you select those rows with `NULL` values you'll get what you want.

Hope this helps.